# Use SED or AWK to move rows to columns

Tags: awk, sed, text-formatting

I have a report that is generated in rows and I need to move it to columns. The number of rows per record will always be the same. This will be in a bash script on Linux, so I would like to use standard tools that are available. I am partial to `awk` and `sed`.

I need to change this:

```
R1
R2
R3
R4
R5
R6
R7
R1
R2
R3
R4
R5
R6
R7
```

To this:

```
R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7
R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've had several people suggest excellent examples that do work with the above data. Unfortunately, my data is a little more robust. Here is a semi real-world example of what I am working with.

This:

```
00000
ND00000056888
Doe, Jane J
F
99 Y
09/01/2014 8:01:08 AM
EE
00001
ND00000056889
Doe, John J
M
66 Y
09/02/2014 5:01:08 PM
DD
```

To:

```
00000;ND00000056888;Doe, Jane J;F;99 Y;09/01/2014 8:01:08 AM;EE
00001;ND00000056889;Doe, John J;M;66 Y;09/02/2014 5:01:08 PM;DD
```

Any delimiter other than a comma or single space will do fine.

Comment: once you change the `,` in Archemar's or my answer to `;`, you get that output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
 awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,NR%7?",":"\n" ; }'
```

the big part

- `NR%7?",":"\n"` : if-then-else :

  - if (NR%7) : NR, (Number of Record) % (modulo) 7 (divide by 7 != 0 )
  - then printf a ','
  - else new line.
- `$0` is the whole line

Answer (score 6):

If you're not stuck on sed or awk, use [paste](http://man.cx/paste)

```
echo "R1
R2
R3
R4
R5
R6
R7
R1
R2
R3
R4
R5
R6
R7" | paste -d, - - - - - - -
```

```
R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7
R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7
```

There's no difficulty with your 2nd sample, just have to quote the semicolon so the shell doesn't see it:

```
paste -d ';' - - - - - - - <filename
```

```
00000;ND00000056888;Doe, Jane J;F;99 Y;09/01/2014 8:01:08 AM;EE
00001;ND00000056889;Doe, John J;M;66 Y;09/02/2014 5:01:08 PM;DD
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this with the filename as an argument ?

Comment: I really like the paste example. Unfortunately, it does not work on my real data. It may be because I have special characters and spaces in each row.

Comment: @Jidder, `paste -d, - - - - - - - < file`

Answer (score 2):

`awk '{ ORS=NR%7?",":"\n" }1'` is another way with awk.

Comment: Could also do it without the brackets as it will always be `,` or `\n` so will always be true. `awk 'ORS=NR%7?",":"\n"'`

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way:

```
pr -a7 -l1 -s";" filename
```

which is short for

```
pr --columns=7 --across --length=1 --separator=";" filename
```